# Zoom inside the plot and show it in the plot

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to zoom a plot inside the show[a,b] command and the zoom portion will be in the plot also?

Comment: Similar to [Magnifying Glass on a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100691/magnifying-glass-on-a-plot)

Comment: yes but now you have to use Show[a,b] command and do that same. Is is possible?

Comment: Related: [How to insert a zoom inside the main plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24526/how-to-insert-a-zoom-inside-the-main-plot?rq=1)